# Running Selenium 2.0 tests siliently

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How do you run Selenium 2.0 tests silently? I'm using it with Capybara. I find the window that pops up annoying. If pops up while I'm typing, I end up entering text in it.

**UPDATE**: I don't mind if it runs with the browser still, I just want it to do all of that in the background.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HtmlUnit Driver via [akephalos](https://github.com/bernerdschaefer/akephalos#readme)

Comment: Unfortunately several tests from and it seems it's a problem with HtmlUnit. The issues are [an xpath one](https://github.com/bernerdschaefer/akephalos/issues#issue/55) and [some js that html unit doesn't like](https://github.com/bernerdschaefer/akephalos/issues/#issue/49). Unforunately I've been trying to fix it for the past hour and I'm afraid I'm going down the route of fixing tests, not the code. I'll try this again in the future.

Comment: have you enabled JavaScript when instantiating your HTMLUnit driver object? (driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);)

Answer (score 0):

Try using xvfb to push it to a display you don't see.

I followed [this](http://www.thefluentadmin.com/silent-selenium-tests/) guide and it all worked for me.